# Gateway attachment failed to delete, but the attachment can't be found. Where is the problem?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Trying to use the Cloud Formation to create a new stack, I'm receiving the follow error when deleting the `stack`:

> Network vpc-1c202306 has some mapped public address(es). Please unmap those public address(es) before detaching the gateway.

After that:

> The following resource(s) failed to delete: [GatewayAttachment].

Configuration:

```
  GatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGatewayID
```

Looking for **all** `AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment`:

```
aws configservice list-discovered-resources --resource-type "AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment"
```

Nothing is found.

Trying the "force delete" for the stack, the AWS shows a message "You may retain resources that are failing to delete" with the `id` of the resource to be ignored on the deletion process:

> GatewayAttachment
>
> spike-Gatew-2OHGCPI1AGQBC

So, where is this `spike-Gatew-2OHGCPI1AGQBC`?